# Where to denote the value of a Duration using Schema.org?

Tags: schema.org

I must be missing something extremely simple here but: where do I denote the actual duration value when marking-up an actual Schema.org [`Duration`](https://schema.org/Duration)?

`Duration` has a couple of properties (all inheriting from [`Thing`](https://schema.org/Thing)), e.g.: `name`, `additionalType`, etc. but I was sort of expecting there to be a property called `value` or something.

From the above link it says the duration is a quantity and should be of format ISO 8601, but where on earth do I put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put them directly as the value of the *Duration* property. For example in **http://schema.org/Invoice**:

```
 property:billingPeriod
 expected type: Duration
```

Setting the billingPeriod from 2014-12-21 with a duration of 30 days in ISO_8601 format, would be `2014-12-21/P30D` and in the code:

```
   <meta itemprop="billingPeriod" content="2014-12-21/P30D" />starts:2014-12-21 30 days
```

*Example from [Invoice schema](http://schema.org/Invoice)

Comment: Not doubting your judgement but isn't this pretty inconsistent from the spec? The Invoice example just shows Duration to be a text value in ISO8601-format. Why then would we need Duration to be a (Structured) Type? Instead Duration being a Datatype inheriting from Text would make much more sense?

Comment: There is another example here: https://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_dates, so I am pretty sure this is the way it should be used. I also agree with you that it could have more specific properties regarding the Duration type, but this is a widely practice in schema.org, for example in all the subtypes of https://schema.org/Quantity or https://schema.org/Date, at least it makes it possible to show where that Type appears as a property in other Type definitions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<time itemprop="duration" datetime="PT12H">12 hours</time>
```

which is equivalent to

```
<meta itemprop="duration" content="PT12H">
```

Duration written in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)